# How does the element section of wasm module in binary format looks?

Tags: binary, webassembly, wasmtime

I am reading [this](https://webassembly.github.io/spec/core/binary/modules.html#binary-elemsec) docs to study wasm binary format. I am finding it very tough to understand the composition of element section. Can someone  please give me an example / explanation about it ? Maybe similar to one given [here](https://coinexsmartchain.medium.com/wasm-introduction-part-1-binary-format-57895d851580)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The element segments section

The idea of this section is to fill the `WebAssembly.Table` objects with content. Initially there was only one table, and its only possible content were indexes/ids of functions. You could write:

```
(elem 0 (offset (i32.const 1)) 2)
```

It means: during the instantiation of the instance fill index `1` of table `0` with a value of `2`, like `tables[0][1] = 2;`. Here `2` is the index of the function the table will store.

The type of element segment above is called `active` nowadays, and after the instantiation it will no longer be accessible by the application (they are "dropped"). From the [specs](https://webassembly.github.io/spec/core/syntax/modules.html#syntax-elemmode):

> An active element segment copies its elements into a table during instantiation, as specified by a table index and a constant expression defining an offset into that table

So far so good. But it was recognized that there is a need for a more powerful element segment section. Introduced were the passive and the declarative element segments.

The passive segment is not used during the instantiation and it is always available at runtime (until is not dropped, by the application itself, with `elem.drop`). There are [instructions](https://webassembly.github.io/spec/core/syntax/instructions.html#syntax-instr-table) (from the `Bulk memory and table instructions` proposal, already integrated into the standard) that can be used to do operations with tables and element segments.

> A declarative element segment is not available at runtime but merely serves to forward-declare references that are formed in code with instructions like ref.func.

Here is the [test suite](https://github.com/WebAssembly/testsuite/blob/main/elem.wast), where you can see many examples of element segments (in a text format).

### The binary format

Assuming that you parser the code, you read one `u32`, and based on its value you expect the format from specification:

- `0` means an active segment, as the one above, for an implicit table index of `0`, and a vector of `func.refs`.
- `1` means a passive segment, the `elemkind` (`0x00` for `func.ref` at this time), followed by a vector of the respective items (`func.refs`).
- `2` is an active segment.
- `3` means a declarative segment.
- `4` is an active segment where the values in the vector are expressions, not just plain indexes (so you could have `(i32.const 2)` in the above example, instead of `2`).
- `5` passive with expressions
- `6` active with table index and expressions
- `7` declarative with expressions

For this reason the specs says that from this `u32` [0..7] you can use its three lower bits to detect what is the format that you have to parse. For example, the 3th bit signifies "is the vector made of expressions?".

---

Now, all that said, it seems that the reference types proposal is not (yet) fully integrated into the specification's binary format (but seems to be in the text one). When it is you will be able to have other then `0x00` (`func.ref`) for an `elemkind`.

It is visible that some of this formats overlap, but the specification evolves, and for backward compatibility reasons with the earliest versions the format is like this today.

Comment: Sir Thank you so much for the answer. It really helped. I have some specific usecase in which I have to use the above concept. Can we have chat about it on stackoverflow chat or any other way ?. ! Please

Comment: or can you please me here https://onlinegdb.com/ByuIzb_83 ( see the last line for instruction)

Comment: You are welcome. You could accept the answer if it is actually an answer to the question (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). If you have other questions, there are many users that might answer to you if you post them in the website.